# Add multiple radio group button dynamically in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, radio-button, survey, android-radiogroup

I've this structure in Android Studio:

> *Question1*
>
> **RadioGroup1**
>
> - RadioButton1
>
>   - RadioButton2
>   - RadioButton3
>   - RadioButton4
>
> *Question2*
>
> **RadioGroup2**
>
> - RadioButton5
>
>   - RadioButton6
>   - RadioButton7
>   - RadioButton8
>
> *Question3*
>
> **RadioGroup3**
>
> - RadioButton9
>
>   - RadioButton10
>   - RadioButton11
>   - RadioButton12
>
> *Question4*
>
> - CheckBox1
>
>   - CheckBox2
>   - CheckBox3
>   - CheckBox4

RadioGroup, RadioButton and Checkbox is created in run time and all is add in LinearLayout.

How get value for example Radiobutton9, Checkbox1, Checkbox3, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can maintain all radio button and,checkbox in list like below example

```
List<RadioButton> list=new ArrayList<>();
list.add(radio_button);

//get value 
String str=list.get(position).getText();
```